# Задать диапазон из несмежных диапазонов

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ одной командой задать диапазон из не смежных столбцов?

Например Range("L9:M" + CStr(n1)).Copy. Хотелось бы, чтобы брался вместо столбца M столбец N, т.е. перепрыгнуть через столбец. Брать каждый по отдельности не совсем устраивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Только знак конкатенации строк в `VBA` не `+`, а знак амперсанда `&`.

Выделить несколько столбцов:

```
' Выделяет столбцы A, B и C
Range("A:A, C:C, E:E").Select
```

Выделить область:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Select
' То же, что и
Range("A1:B3").Select
```

Выделить разные столбцы, ячейки и области:

```
Range("A:A, F3, E7:F9").Select
' То же, что и
Range("A:A, F" & CStr(3) & ", E" & CStr(7) & ":F" & CStr(9)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Если с несмежными диапазонами предполагаются дальнейшие не разовые действия, имеет смысл присвоить диапазон переменной:

```
Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A2:A5, F3, E7:F9") 
    r.Select
```

В процессе диапазон можно изменять:

```
Sub TestRng()
Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A2:A5, F3, E7:F9") ' создаем диапазон
    r.Value = 1

    Set r = Union(r, Range("C7, D4:D8")) ' пополняем диапазон
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 100, 100)

    Set r = Nothing ' освобождаем память
End Sub
```